# Post array to ASP NET MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my javascript method:

```
this.ingressoMerce = function () {
    operationLogs = new Array();
    ordersToUpdate = new Array();

    $('.position-checkb').each(function (index, obj) {
        if (this.checked === true) {
            let positionNumber = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').text();
            let qtaRicevute = $(this).parent().parent().find(".qta-ricevute-txt").val();
            let qtaOrdine = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(5)').text();
            let qtaGiaRicevute = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(7)').text();

            if (parseInt(qtaOrdine) > 0 && (parseInt(qtaRicevute) + parseInt(qtaGiaRicevute) <= parseInt(qtaOrdine))) {

                var orderToUpdate = Utils.getAllData().toJSON().find(x => x.Posizione == positionNumber);

                orderToUpdate.ReceivedQty = parseInt(qtaRicevute);
                ordersToUpdate.push(orderToUpdate);

                $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(7)').text(qtaRicevute);

                let operationName = "Ingresso merce";

                let operationLog = {};
                operationLog.OperationQty = qtaRicevute;
                operationLog.OperationDate = new Date();
                operationLog.OrderDetailOperationTypeRelations = ['Ingresso merce'];

                operationLogs.push(operationLog);
            } else {
                alert("La quantità inserita supererebbe la quantità totale dell'ordine, ricontrollare")
            }
        }
    });

    console.log('Orders to update', ordersToUpdate);
    console.log('Logs', operationLogs);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: updateOrderDetailUrl,
        content: "application/json;",            
        data: { ordersToUpdate: ordersToUpdate },
    }).done(function () {
        alert('ok fatto, chiamare log');
    });
}
```

And here is the method that is called in the controller:

```
[HttpPut("/UpdateOrderDetails")]
    public async Task UpdateOrderDetails(List<Contracts.OrderDetail> ordersToUpdate)
    {
        await orderService.UpdateOrderDetails(ordersToUpdate);
    }
```

The problem is that the array when arrives to the controller has Count = 0. Instead in the javascript code is populated. I can't figure out where I am mistakening.

Comment: Have you verified there is some data in `console.log('Orders to update', ordersToUpdate);` before making the ajax call?

Comment: @palash actually it does not write anything in the Chrome console. I am a newbie on this, where could be  the problem. But the array is not empty. I checked it in debug mode. I just don't understand why it does not log it and I get an array with 0 count in the controller